# binutils not able to find isl

Tags: cygwin, gcc-warning, binutils

yes this question has been asked before. no the other answers doesn't solve my problem.

I have just built isl from source both 0.15 and 0.22.
I have isl and I know where it is and I am amazed that even though I have pointed to where the program is in configure binutils can't find it.

It did work a few months ago to do it this way.

```sh
../gitrepos/binutils/configure --prefix=/tools --with-sysroot=x86_64-w64-cygwin --with-lib-path=/tools/lib --disable-nls --disable-werror lt_cv_objdir=.libs --target=x86_64-w64-cygwin --with-isl=/home/brazg/usr/isl/0.22
```

> I am getting the following error: required isl version is 0.15 or
>   later configure: error: Unable to find a usable isl.  See config.log
>   for details.

```
/tmp/cc3B0zAy.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cc3B0zAy.s:14: Error: unknown .loc sub-directive `view'
/tmp/cc3B0zAy.s:14: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `-'
/tmp/cc3B0zAy.s:20: Error: unknown .loc sub-directive `view'
/tmp/cc3B0zAy.s:20: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.lvu1'
/tmp/cc3B0zAy.s:23: Error: unknown .loc sub-directive `view'
/tmp/cc3B0zAy.s:23: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.lvu2'
configure:5079: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
```

Yes I am aware that there are a whole lot of assembler errors because of the version of GCC in Cygwin.  I am trying to replace it by building a more current version of gcc.

This is a common problem I have been running into. when building some source code in Cygwin.  It seems one of the programs that runs into this is binutils...

I'm not sure what to do.

and yes, I could try cross compiling in Linux, no I don't want to and I'm hoping I don't have to. I'd like to do this naively to Windows if I can.

Comment: cygwin provide the package 0.16. Any reason to not use it ?

Comment: yeah. its not detected either https://i.gyazo.com/549434dbeff60edff89f05d2b4dbf98e.png

Comment: the configure flags used for the screen capture:  ../gitrepos/binutils/configure --prefix=/tools --with-sysroot=x86_64-w64-cygwin --with-lib-path=/tools/lib --disable-nls --disable-werror lt_cv_objdir=.libs --target=x86_64-w64-cygwin

Comment: have you looked on the `config.log` to see why it does not detect it ?

Comment: why `x86_64-w64-cygwin`  ? For Cygwin purpose the default is  `x86_64-pc-cygwin` and you do not need to specify it. Are you trying to build a cross-compiler ?

Comment: it just spews out this junk: https://pastebin.com/1as83Lwz I can't make any sense of it. As far as I've figured out from searching on it, it is a compiler error due to some incompatibility in the version of GCC

Comment: It ends by saying I must set the environment variable CC to a working compiler.  Which is it because it was installed with Cygwin.

Comment: I chose `w64` because I wanted to be more specific then just saying `pc`. Since its the vender I thought maybe specifying that its a windows machine would make sense.  Also when configuring many times the  configure script will just find the vender to be unknown.  So I wanted to give it something more meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are complicating yourself the life (`x86_64-pc-cygwin` is platform specific, not your choice) and you should start using the standard cygport tool, the same configuration already used for the `binutils` cygwin package and the `isl 0.16.1` available. When you have problem with `configure` the proper config.log will provide the hint on what is going wrong.

Herebelow the a recipe to build the last released binutils 2.33.1 and create a cygwin package. For my test I am using the stable packages:

```
$ cygcheck -cd binutils gcc-core libisl-devel
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version
binutils             2.31.1-1
gcc-core             7.4.0-1
libisl-devel         0.16.1-1
```

but you can also try with the test 8.3.0-1 gcc compiler.

Download the source package and extract the `binutils.cygport`

```
$ wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/cygwin/x86/release/binutils/binutils-2.31.1-1-src.tar.xz

$ tar -xf binutils-2.31.1-1-src.tar.xz

$ cp  binutils-2.31.1-1.src/binutils.cygport .
```

Adjusting the cygport file to build from release 2.33.1 and not from git

```
$ cat binutils.cygport
TOOLCHAIN_TARGET="native"
# GIT_URI="git://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git"
# inherit toolchain git
# GIT_REV=be46fa23042ec88a7a42030476a301bf72a80e7e
# SRC_DIR=binutils-gdb

NAME="binutils"
VERSION=2.33.1
RELEASE=1
CATEGORY="Devel"
SUMMARY="GNU assembler, linker, and similar utilities"
DESCRIPTION="This directory contains various GNU compilers, assemblers, linkers,
debuggers, etc., plus their support routines, definitions, and documentation."
HOMEPAGE="http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/"
case ${VERSION} in
*.*.[5-9][0-9])
        SRC_URI="ftp://sourceware.org/pub/binutils/snapshots/binutils-${VERSION}.tar.bz2" ;;
*)      SRC_URI="mirror://gnu/binutils/binutils-${VERSION}.tar.xz"
        SRC_DIR=${PN}-${PV}
        ;;
esac
#PATCH_URI+=" 2.24.51-shared-libs.patch"
#2.24.51-ld-__dso_handle.patch
#PATCH_URI+="
#2.24.51-ld-__dso_handle.patch
#detect-rebasing-and-compute-an-address-bias.patch
#"

#PATCH_URI="e643cb45bf85fa5c8c49a89ff177de246af4212e.patch"
# gdb,etc.: https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2014-01/msg00341.html
# for shared libbfd/libopcodes, add:
#       --enable-shared
CYGCONF_ARGS="
        --enable-install-libiberty
        --disable-gdb
        --disable-libdecnumber
        --disable-readline
        --disable-sim
        --enable-64-bit-bfd
"
# --enable-targets=i686-efi-pe,x86_64-efi-pe,ia64-efi-elf,x86_64-pc-cygwin,i686-pc-cygwin

src_install() {
        cd ${B}
        cyginstall

        # for shared libbfd/libopcodes, add:
        # APIs are unstable, do not allow linking against DLLs
#       rm -f ${D}/usr/lib/*.dll.a
#       sed -i -e '/^library_names=/d' ${D}/usr/lib/lib*.la
}
```

As you can note that I have NOT changed the arguments of binutils configuration. So now I can build the 2.33.1 package:

```
$  cygport binutils.cygport download
...
binutils-2.33.1.tar 100%[===================>]  20.50M  1.50MB/s    in 15s

2020-01-04 17:07:52 (1.38 MB/s) - ‘binutils-2.33.1.tar.xz.tmp’ saved [21490848/21490848]

$ cygport binutils.cygport almostall
>>> Preparing binutils-2.33.1-1.x86_64
>>> Unpacking source binutils-2.33.1.tar.xz
>>> Preparing working source directory
...
>>> Creating source patches
 0 files changed
>>> Creating source package
binutils-2.33.1-1.src/
binutils-2.33.1-1.src/binutils-2.33.1.tar.xz
binutils-2.33.1-1.src/binutils.cygport

>>> binutils requires: cygwin libgcc1
```

and you can also test the build:

```
$ cygport binutils.cygport check

                === binutils Summary ===

# of expected passes            136
# of unexpected failures        1
# of expected failures          1
# of unsupported tests          5
```

I notice an hang at the end of the test, but the check seems completed, co it could be to other factors that I will not investigate.